# error with authen in google-api-php

Tags: php

I'm trying to run this script:

```
require_once('autoload.php');
require_once('Client.php');

$client = new Google_Client();

        $client->setClientId('my clientid');
        $client->setClientSecret('my secret');
        $client->setDeveloperKey('my developer key');
        $client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->setRedirectUri(null);
        $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics'));



$service    =   new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

// get accounts from analytics
$accounts   = $service->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
```

But then, it's giving me this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with
>   message
>   '{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required","message":"Login
>   Required","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Login
>   Required"}}' in
>   /root/google-api/google-api-php-client-2.0.0-RC5/src/Google/Http/REST.php:129
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 /root/google-api/google-api-php-client-2.0.0-RC5/src/Google/Http/REST.php(88):
>   Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
>   #1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
>   #2 /root/google-api/google-api-php-client-2.0.0-RC5/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(181):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>   #3 /root/google-api/google-api-php-client-2.0.0-RC5/src/Google/Http/REST.php(57):
>   Google_Task_Runner->run()
>   #4 /root/google-api/google-api-php-client-2.0.0-RC5/src/Google/Client.php(758):
>   Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(GuzzleH in
>   /root/google-api/google-api-php-client-2.0.0-RC5/src/Google/Http/REST.php
>   on line 129

Why?

Comment: Have you tried to read any documentation and/or debug?

Answer (score 0):

You need a valid redirectUri instead of null.

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app